# Unable to start new activity using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am calling an activity and also transferring the values from adapter to the next activity the values are transferred but unable to star the activity and also there is no error just the next activity doesn't open

**Holder:**

```
public class ContactReadHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView contactName, contactPhone;
    ImageButton contactCall;
    public ContactReadHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        context =itemView.getContext();

        contactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_list_name);
        contactPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_list_phone);
        contactCall = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_list_call);
    }
}
```

This s my adapter code and i have implented listner in the onBindViewHolder but still it soesn't work and also i have tried in Holder class also

**Adapter:**

```
public class ContactReadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactReadAdapter.ContactReadHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<ContactListModel> contactListModelList;
    private Context context;

    public ContactReadAdapter(List<ContactListModel> contactListModelList, Context context) {

        this.contactListModelList = contactListModelList;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContactReadHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_contact_layout, parent, false);

        ContactReadHolder contactReadHolder = new ContactReadHolder(view);
        return contactReadHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContactReadHolder holder, int position) {

        final TextView contactName, contactPhone;

        contactName = holder.contactName;
        contactPhone = holder.contactPhone;

        contactName.setText(contactListModelList.get(position).getModel_contact_name());
        contactPhone.setText(contactListModelList.get(position).getModel_contact_phone());

        holder.contactCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("duit","clicked ");
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,OutgoingCallActivity.class);
                String string_contactName=holder.contactName.getText().toString();
                String string_contactPhone=holder.contactPhone.getText().toString();

                Log.d("duit","clicked " + string_contactName +" "+  string_contactPhone);
                intent.putExtra("user_name",string_contactName);
                intent.putExtra("calleeNumber", string_contactPhone);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactListModelList.size();
    }
```

Comment: your conclick is getting triggered ?? ryt??

Comment: @SantanuSur yeah it is working i checked in the log

Comment: i have updated my answer please check..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),OutgoingCallActivity.class);
 // put extra methods
 v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: also i have tried yours in both ways but doesn't work

Comment: issue is activity not opening ? @AvadaKedavra ??

Comment: yes activity is not opening and also not showing any error

Comment: try uninstalling the app manually  , then installing it again , then check in manifest if the activity is declared or not..post your manifest file .. @AvadaKedavra

Comment: where is the recyclerView ?? activity ?? post your adapter calling code... @AvadaKedavra

Comment: your build.gradle ? which support version are you using ? @AvadaKedavra

Comment: and most probably you have issue in the activity in some phones log doesnt show up @AvadaKedavra

Comment: post your `OutgoingCallActivity.class` and its xml @AvadaKedavra

Comment: surely you are using phone ryt ?? not emulator eryt ?? @AvadaKedavra then its log not showing..

Answer (score 0):

Write your **onclicklistener** on **onBindViewHolder** function and it will work.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to respond more verbosely? There is already an OnClickListener shown there. Does it need to do more? Describe the OnBindViewHolder that you recommend. --- sorry, Avada, I had mistyped "question"

Comment: @sorak have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
       Intent intent=new Intent(contactName.getContext(),OutgoingCallActivity.class);
        String string_contactName=holder.contactName.getText().toString();
        String string_contactPhone=holder.contactPhone.getText().toString();

        Log.d("duit","clicked " + string_contactName +" "+  string_contactPhone);
        intent.putExtra("user_name",string_contactName);
        intent.putExtra("calleeNumber", string_contactPhone);

        contactName.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
               Intent intent=new Intent(holder.contactName.getContext(),OutgoingCallActivity.class);
            String string_contactName=holder.contactName.getText().toString();
            String string_contactPhone=holder.contactPhone.getText().toString();

            Log.d("duit","clicked " + string_contactName +" "+  string_contactPhone);
            intent.putExtra("user_name",string_contactName);
            intent.putExtra("calleeNumber", string_contactPhone);

            holder.contactName.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```